# Javascript stops when first if condition fails, need to move it to second condition

Tags: javascript

I have the following code in which I ask it to check if either one of 2 dataLayer values is "!= false" then run the rest of the code.

However, code breaks as soon as the first condition fails and does not move to check the second condition. So, how can I let both conditions be checked as one of them will always be available in dataLayer?

```
function init() {
    if (dataLayer.condition[1] != false || dataLayer.condition[2] != false) {
        Do something
    }
    
}
```

Below is the screenshot of the error I get when the first condition values are missing on the page.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [optional chaining (`?.`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) for this, if your [execution context is expected to support it](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_operators_optional_chaining):

```
if (dataLayer?.condition[1] != false || dataLayer?.condition[2] != false) {
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: i would also like to mention that dataLayer?.condition[1] != false is the same as dataLayer?.condition[1] == true which can be shortend to dataLayer?.condition[1] so you could just write if (dataLayer?.condition[1] || dataLayer?.condition[2) {